# Watchdog an application from a service

Tags: windows, service, desktop-application, watchdog

How can I make a service to be a watchdog for a desktop application knowing that [Services cannot/shouldn't interact with Desktop applications](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/f8f91e8f-5954-43a7-8bc4-80ed2ff1e3b1).

Or is it only working assuming there is only one user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service can not have a UI but they can run executables.
It is just that for windows vista, windows 7 and on, the service need to find out under which user/session to run the executable.

Here is a blog post explaining how to do [that].[1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx)